# pod install error: The name of the given podspec `Yoga` doesn't match the expected one `yoga`

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, expo, pod-install

I'm getting the following error while doing pod install.

```
The name of the given podspec `Yoga` doesn't match the expected one `yoga`
```

Inside the Podfile these are the only lines with the word yoga and they are in lowercase...so I don't know what's causing this problem..

```
pod 'yoga',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it should be `pod 'Yoga'`. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec#L18

Answer (score 0):

When you `.podfile` `pod '<name>'` is not equal `.podspec` `<variable>.name         = "name"` you get

```
The name of the given podspec `<name>` doesn't match the expected one
```